# how to send results in graph in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I want To send The Results of Performance Testing in form of Graph in mail
I am Using "Response Time Graph" Listener to Generate Graph
I am Using "SMTP Sampler" Sampler To Send Mail

The Results Are Send In Csv File
I Want The Results In Graphical Format

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send a chart I would suggest taking the next steps:

1. First of all install [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/). You can do it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager Command Line Graph Plotting tool]
2. Once done somewhere in [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group)

   - Generate the required chart, i.e. `ResponseTimesOverTime` using `JMeterPluginsCMD` script and your .jtl results file via [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)
   - Send the generated image using the [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler)

Comment: I have Added Following Things in My Thread Group
1.OS Process Sampler
2.SMTP Sampler
3.ResponseTimesOverTime

What Should I Configure in OS Process Sampler?


I have Configured Mail Server Details In SMTP Sampler
I have Configured ResponseTimesOverTime and I am Receiving Mail With Logs in CSV (not In Graphs)